# WSO2 limited edition access to API in publisher

Tags: api, wso2, product, multi-tenant

I'm sorry if this isn't the proper place to ask the question, I've been looking around and I feel like there's something I don't understand in the WSO2 API publisher.

As API manager global admin, I provide several tenants with their API stores. Let's say Goodies and Baddies.

As a Goodie, I'd like an API provider, let's call it AC, to add an API to my store.
I'd like another API provider, let's say DC, to do the same.
I'd like them to avoid modifying each other's APIs. They can see them is necessary, but not modify them.

As a goodie I can create roles in my tenancy store. If they want to create APIs, AC and DC both need the role Creator, with the right to "create" APIs.
But if they are creators, they will both be able to edit *all* APIs in goodie's API store.

So to achieve what I want, I would need one tenancy for AC and one tenancy for DC!

That's not what what I wanted. I would like APIs to be editable only by their creator.

To achieve this, it seems I have to create a tenancy for each editor. However I already have a system of tenancies. So I have the tenancy AC with APIs of AC, and I have to restrict them to Goodies. But the admin of tenancy Goodies can't create any tenancy, so they will have to ask the APIM global admin for a new tenancy!

This is not as simple as creating a user with role creator for the API provider in the tenancy Goodies. :-(

How does this work out?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer, I received an answer from WSO2.

I cannot achieve what I want. It will be available in a further release.